# jQuery .hide function not working

Tags: jquery, hide

Hy guys and hope you can help.

I have a very simple jQuery hide function that was working but some bugInTheRom has occured overnight and it no longer does. Effectively I'm trying to add a 'Patience' warning visible whilst some SWF loads.

Here's my call in the `<head>` section...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hidden() {
    $('.patience').hide();
};
window.onload=hidden;
</script>
```

and here's the class it affects...

```
<p class="patience">Please be patient, the interactive book below and the PDF links may take a while to fully load.</p>
```

and the associated CSS...

```
.patience {
    visibility: visible;
    background-color: #CCC;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Any ideas why it doesn't hide once the whole of the SWF has been loaded?

My thanks.
R

Comment: does it not hide at all, or does it hide too early?

Answer (score 3):

If you're having problems, I would switch to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('.patience').hide();
    });
});
```

which might help everything initialize properly.

I'm not sure I understand how the SWF is related... perhaps you meant to say `swf_elem.onload` or something instead of `window.onload`?

Comment: @Rog did you test this one?  It's the cleanest answer, and also considers that there may be some other event being fired by the SWF loader.

Comment: Thanks both to @Mu Mind and @Alnitak, I tried this and, sadly, it didn't work. It's live here, rogw.net/lulworth . @Alnitak, thanks for your perserverence, I'll hunt out a JS debugger.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing change `window.onload=hidden;` to `$(function(){hidden();});`

The new way i suggested is using jQuery's version of `document ready` which makes sure that the elements that you might want to affect are loaded and can be used.

Also i see nothing in your code which connects this `hidden()` function to any SWF load

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/XX8ym/

Comment: Wouldn't `$(hidden);` be more efficient?

Comment: @Ender, that is under the assumption that the OP does not want to do anything else on startup, yes.

Comment: Thanks Neal, I deliberately skipped including all the |SWF load stuff, I'll experiment with your new function call and come back.

Comment: From the Mozilla docs: `The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images and sub-frames have finished loading.`  Basically, this means that onload is called when the DOM is loaded, but not necessarily when a plugin is loaded.  As @Neal mentioned, you need to see if flash will raise an event once loaded and bind to that.

Comment: @Neal `$(func())` is the same as `$(document).ready(...)` which _doesn't_ wait for sub-elements to load the way that `window.onload` does.

Comment: Also, something I just noticed - OP is trying to run his function on page load, whereas our suggestions would execute the function on DOM ready. Minor difference, but could be important.

Comment: @Neal: you may want to suggest why he should change to jQuery's `ready`. With _what he's supplied_, I don't see a reason his simple `onload` doesn't solve the same problem.

Comment: @Ender, but on pageload `.patience` might not be available yet

Comment: OK, thanks all, I've changed window.onload to Neal's $(function)(){hidden();}); definition but same problem. The .patience content remains on screen.

Comment: @Ender, I don't want anything else on startup so will explore $(hidden);

Comment: @Rog -- it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/XX8ym/ . look in the console to make sure you dont have js errors elsewhere.

Comment: @Neal you've still got this the wrong way around - `document.ready` only requires that the DOM elements are in place - `window.onload` waits until they're all actually loaded.

Comment: Guys, you're amazing with the speed of your response. I can't keep up with your input but thought I'd add my simplistic functionality which is that I want to display a 'patience' message whislt the SWF loads and then remove it after the SWF load has been completed.

Comment: @Alnitak -- try my fiddle with `window.onload` - it does not work

Comment: @Neal sure it does - jsfiddle wraps with `window.onload` by default!  See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/yQ3Pd/

Comment: @Alnitak -- thanks the 'Patience' warning stays on screen rather than, my hoped for, being removed.

Comment: @Rog as suggested elsewhere, check your JS console for errors.  There's no reason your posted code shouldn't work - if anything it'll hide the text _before_ the SWF has loaded.

Comment: @Alnitak - good point! This may be the cause of my problem so I guess I need to,
a) call the SWF load function,
b) and then call the hide function.
Does that sound sensible?

Comment: Hi you great contributors, my code checks out OK with jsfiddle and others so I'm still at a loss. Is this a sequencing issue as per @Alnitak's comment i.e. do I need to call the SWF load prior to the hide function?
My thanks to all,
R

Answer (score 1):

Firstly - `window.onload` is the right place to put this handler - unlike `$(document).ready()` it will wait until all sub-frames, images, etc, have loaded.

What I don't know is whether `window.onload` will also wait for an SWF object to be loaded.

If it *doesn't* wait for the SWF, then the effect would be that your `.patience` div will disappear *too* early, since the rest of the page will have finished loaded.

It it does wait, but your div isn't disappearing at all, this suggests that you've simply got a trivial error somewhere in your real JS code that is preventing the `.hide()` from ever being called.

Since you've said that the div isn't disappearing, I would suggest that you've got the latter problem, in which case a few minutes with a JS debugger should reveal (no pun intended) the problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be your jQuery failed to load. Also, when using jQuery, use jQuery's $.ready instead of window.onload to ensure all things are in peace before trying to do anything!

Answer (score 0):

My stupid mistake!

Nothing wrong with the code I showed you but I discovered that I was calling 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>`in the head and only the "js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" script existed on my server.

Feel stupid now but thanks all who contributed.

Cheers
Rog